# how to add comments referring to a piece of code or #region in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a piece of code, say an if-condition on line 2000. This code completely depends upon the output from another piece of code on line 1000. So I need to write a comment on line 2000 to refer to line 1000.

So, how can I write a cref kind of comment on line 2000 in order to click and navigate to the line 1000?

Eg.,

```
ln 1000 

int count = 100;
count += some-condition;

ln 2000
if (count-condition)
{
  statement;//this condition depends on the piece of code on **<cref reference>ln 1000 or region**
}
```

Comment: Split your code into methods and refer method names in comments.

Comment: You mentioned [cref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/cref-attribute), it supports method names refactoring ([proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFE7x.png)).

Comment: so, there is no method to refer using inline comments(//)?

Comment: `//` and `/* */` comments are simple comments. Theoretically you can make addon to VS to do whatever you want. Your request sounds exotic, in C# line numbers are not something to reference for a long term (debugging is another topic). I doubt addon like this exists. By default there are [///](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/) comments with intellisence/compliler/IDE support, rather try to use those.

Comment: @Sinatr I understand navigating to a line number doesn't make sense, but referring to a piece of code through a region or something else is a genuine request. I have provided line numbers as an example.

Answer (score 0):

If your method is becoming too big, you should start thinking about refactoring, creating smaller ones.

As I now today, you can't do this with normal comments.

When I need to accomplish such task I use XML method comments.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Does something
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Some integer </returns>
    public int foo()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Does something
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Some int taken from <seealso cref="foo"/> method</param>
    public void bar(int value)
    {

    }
```

If you press F12 in bar method, you'll see the comment. When you press F12 in the "foo" inside the `<seealso cref="foo"/>`, you'll go right to the "foo" method definition.

Plus: If you rename "foo" method, it'll also update the documentation.

Comment: so, there is no method to refer using inline comments(//)?

Comment: there is no xml comments using "//"

Comment: If you put // <seealso cref="foo"/> or /* <seealso cref="foo"/> */, 
it wont work when you press F12, or rename it, etc.

Comment: yes, it wont work, but is there any other way that I can refer to a piece of code in comments either through #region or some other way. I believe we don't have.

Comment: You really should try to reorganize your code. I mean, don't try to put a reference in the line 1000 pointing to somewhere in line 2000. Split your method in several ones, and later, use the approach I suggested.

Comment: Search about DRY or SOLID principles. Look at this: DRY stand for "Don't Repeat Yourself," a basic principle of software development aimed at reducing repetition of information. The DRY principle is stated as, "Every piece of knowledge or logic must have a single, unambiguous representation within a system."

Comment: S from SOLID principles: Single Responsibility Principle: 
The Single Responsibility Principle is the most abstract of the bunch. It helps keep classes and methods small and maintainable. In addition to keeping classes small and focused it also makes them easier to understand.